# How to deference a reference to a scalar in an array

Tags: perl

I have following piece of code

```
$var1 = 10;

@arr = (1, \$var1, 3);

print "var1= $$arr[1] \n";
```

This is not printing value 10, is this syntax `$$arr[1]` correct?
using additional variable i was able to print the value

```
$r = $var[1];

print "var1 = $$r\n";
```

Comment: Need `print "var1= ${$arr[1]}\n";`  I suggest to read over [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: `$$arr[1]`, short for `${ $arr }[1]`, and equivalent to `$arr->[1]`, is for when you have a reference to an array, and you want the second element of the referenced array. You have a reference to a scalar.

Answer (score 5):

If it's `$NAME` if you have the name, it's `$BLOCK` if you have a reference. So,

```
${ $arr[1] }
```

or (5.24+)

```
$arr[1]->$*
```

or (5.20+)

```
use experimental qw( postderef );

$arr[1]->$*
```

References:

- [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)
- [References Quick Reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print "var1 = ${ $var[1] }\n" ;
```