# find nested array length in perl

Tags: perl

I have deference array as given below -

```
"message": [
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
     "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
     "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    }
  ]
```

To find its length I tried following stuff but in each case I got answer as '1' instead of '5'.

```
1. say scalar @message;
2. my $attempt_length = @message;
```

It might be a very basic question but I am stuck here very badly. Please, help me in finding its length in **Perl** if anyone can.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `message` an array, or an *array ref*? If it is an array ref, then you want `say scalar @$message`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a reference to a variable instead of a variable name, you simply replace the name in the syntax you want to use with a block that evaluate to the reference.

If you have the name of an array, you'd use the following to get its size:

```
@NAME             # In scalar context
```

If you have a reference to an array, you'd use the following to get its size:

```
@BLOCK            # In scalar context
```

So, if `$messages` contains a reference to an array, the following will get its size.

```
@{ $messages }    # In scalar context
```

You can omit the curlies if they contain a simple scalar (`$NAME`).

```
@$messages        # In scalar context
```

So,

```
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $json = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $data = decode_json($json);
my $messages = $data->{message};
my $num_messages = @$messages;    # Or:  @{ $data->{message} }

__DATA__
{
  "message": [
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
      "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
     "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    },
    {
     "abc": "",
      "xyz": "",
      "pqr": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `@$arrayref` and `@{ $arrayref }` syntaxes ikegami already mentioned, I want to mention postfix dereferencing (available since perl v5.24, or with `use experimental 'postderef'` since perl v5.20)

```
my $num_of_elems = $arrayref->@*;         # implicit scalar context
my $num_of_elems = scalar $arrayref->@*;  # explicit scalar context
```