# Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at indent2tree

Tags: perl

I realize similar questions have been asked. However, in this case I wish to use this open source perl script:

https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/blob/master/usr/bin/indent2tree

This line is producing the error `Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at /usr/local/bin/indent2tree line 43, near "};"`

```
push $ForkPoint->{subtree}, {data=>$data, parent=>$ForkPoint, subtree=>[]};
```

I am not very familiar with Perl. I did check several questions on this topic and I tried to fix the issue a few different ways without success.

For example:

```
push @ForkPoint->{subtree}, {data=>$data, parent=>$ForkPoint, subtree=>[]};
```

That still produces the error.

Since my goal here is to just use the tool, maybe someone who is familiar with Perl can share the solution. I opened a [bug](https://github.com/bAndie91/tools/issues/3) at the project issue page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
push @{ $ForkPoint->{subtree} }, ...
```

---

Whenever you can use the name of a variable, you can use a block that evaluates to a reference instead. That means the following are valid syntax for specifying an array:

```
@NAME    # If you have the name
@BLOCK   # If you have a reference
```

That means that the following two snippets are equivalent:

```
push @arary, ...
```

```
my $ref = \@array;
push @{ $ref }, ...
```

While not relevant in this case, you can omit the curlies when the only thing in the block is a simple scalar (`$NAME` or `$BLOCK`).

```
push @$ref, ...
```

---

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).