# Perl: Systematically dereferencing elements of anonymous array

Tags: perl, anonymous-types

The following gives me a compilation error `Global symbol "$list" requires explicit package name at ./scratch line 19.`. How can I correctly access an element in an anonymous array?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature "say";

my @list1 = (10, 20, 30);
my @list2 = ("hello", "yellow", "mellow");
my $r1 = \@list1;
my $r2 = \@list2;

my @list = ($r1, $r2);

# Prints just fine
say join ", ", @$r1;
say join ", ", @$r2;

# This part gives compilation error
say join ", ", @$list[0];
say join ", ", @$list[1];
```

Comment: Maybe: `@{ $list[0] }`?

Comment: @GMB, Thanks, that works! Do you happen to know why sticking an "@" before `$list[0]` doesn't work like `@$r1` does?

Comment: Precedence issue. (You can also use [postderef syntax](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) - `$list[0]->@*`)

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References where this is mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

`@$list[0]` is short for `@{ $list }[0]` but you want `@{ $list[0] }` (or `$list[0]->@*`).

---

```
@array[1,2,3]
```

is an array slice equivalent to

```
( $array[1], $array[2], $array[3] )
```

The syntax for an array slice is

```
@NAME[LIST]     # Named array
@BLOCK[LIST]    # A block returning a reference.
EXPR->@[LIST]   # An expression returning a reference.   Perl 5.24+
```

For example,

```
@array[1,2,3]
@{ $ref }[1,2,3]
$ref->@[1,2,3]
```

When the block contains only a simple scalar (`$NAME` or `$BLOCK`), the curlies of the block can be omitted.

For example,

```
@{ $ref }[1,2,3]
```

can be written as

```
@$ref[1,2,3]
```

This is what you had, but not you wanted. You wanted the elements of an array.

```
@NAME      # Named array
@BLOCK     # A block returning a reference.
EXPR->@*   # An expression returning a reference.   Perl 5.24+
```

For example,

```
@array
@{ $ref }
$ref->@*
```

Or in your case,

```
@{ $list[0] }
$list[0]->@*
```

As with an array slice, the curlies of the block can be omitted when the block contains only a simple scalar. But that's not what you have.

---

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).