# Perl: Combine hash with Keys of Keys containing identical Key

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap, key

I am trying to merge these hashmaps in perl and unable to figure out how to do it when the key is identical. The desired input is VAR1 and VAR2 and output is mentioned as well.

Input:

```
my $VAR1 = { 'p'=> { 'a' => 2,
                     'b' => 3}};


my $VAR2 = { 'p'=> { 'c' => 4,
                     'd' => 7}};
```

Desired Output:

```
{'p'=> { 
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 3,
        'c' => 4,
        'd' => 7}};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you had

```perl
my %h1 = ( a => 2, b => 3 );
my %h2 = ( c => 4, d => 7 );
```

To combine them into a third hash, you can use

```perl
my %h = ( %h1, %h2 );
```

It would be as if you had done

```perl
my %h = ( a => 2, b => 3, c => 4, d => 7 );
```

Any keys in common will be taken from the hash later in the list.

---

In your case, you have anonymous hashes. So where we would have used `%NAME`, we will use `%BLOCK`, where the block returns a reference to the hash we want to use. This gives us the following:

```perl
my %h_inner = (
   %{ $VAR1->{p} },
   %{ $VAR2->{p} },
);
```

This can also be written as follows:<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
my %h_inner = (
   $VAR1->{p}->%*,
   $VAR2->{p}->%*,
);
```

Finally, you also want to second new hash with a single element keyed with `p` whose value is a reference to this first new hash.

```perl
my %h_outer = ( p => \%h_inner );
```

---

So, all together, you want

```perl
my %h_inner = (
   %{ $VAR1->{p} },
   %{ $VAR2->{p} },
);

my %h_outer = ( p => \%h_inner );
```

We could also use the anonymous hash constructor (`{}`) instead.

```perl
my %h_outer = (
   p => {
      %{ $VAR1->{p} },
      %{ $VAR2->{p} },
   },
};
```

Docs:

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

---

1. Check version compatibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).

Comment: Hi, This is what I am getting with output.

my %h1 = ( a => 2, b => 3 );
my %h2 = ( c => 4, d => 7 );
my %h = ( %h1, %h2 );
my %h = (
   %{ $VAR1->{p} },
   %{ $VAR2->{p} },
);

warn Dumper(%h);
$VAR2 = 4;
$VAR3 = 'a';
$VAR4 = 2;                                                                                                                                        
$VAR5 = 'b';
$VAR6 = 3;
$VAR7 = 'd';
$VAR8 = 7

Comment: You are passing the keys and values to Dumper, just like you did to the assignment in the third statement. And, as you can see, they are the correct keys and values. That said, don't pass arrays and hashes to `Dumper`; pass references to them instead. You'll get something easier to read using `Dumper(\%h)`.

Comment: Sorry but the p is gone in the output.
{'a' => 2,
'b' => 3,
'c' => 4,
'd' => 7}

Comment: Added to my answer.