# Need to understand perl reference by clarifying these 4 patterns

Tags: perl

I really really don't undertand perl hash. I have been reading perl doc but not able to completely get perl reference.

For a prime example, can you please tell me the difference between below?

```
 @{$table}{$item}
 @{$table{$item}}
 %{$table}{$item}
 %{$table{$item}}
```

Or is there some general rule that I am missing from not able to decipher these?

Please point me to right direction. I have been reading perldoc.perl.org..

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol and https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc are a good place to start

Comment: For references see [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) and [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref). Also see [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata)

Comment: thanks guys,  I went through them lightly. If there is an answer in these, I will go through them more throughly. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the reference-producing block (`{ ... }`) with an identifier to get a better sense of what you have.

- `@{$table}{$item}`

  - Akin to `@name{$item}`
  - Array slice of the array referenced by `$table`
  - Can also be written as `$table->@{$item}`
  - There's no point to using a slice when there's only one item returned by the index expression. Should be `${$table}{$item}` or `$table->{$item}`.
- `@{$table{$item}}`

  - Akin to `@name`
  - Array referenced by `$table{$item}`
  - Can also be written as `$table{$item}->@*`
- `%{$table}{$item}`

  - Akin to `%name{$item}`
  - Key-value hash slice of the hash referenced by `$table`
  - Can also be written as `$table->%{$item}`
- `%{$table{$item}}`

  - Akin to `%name`
  - Hash referenced by `$table{$item}`
  - Can also be written as `$table{$item}->%*`

See

- [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref)

Comment: what is this suppose to be?? Akin to %name{$item}

Comment: [A hash key-value slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Key/Value-Hash-Slices)