# Can't resolve scalars from Perl arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a Perl reference to a hash `$conf` that has an array as one of the values. I can retrieve it by:

```
$conf->{group}->{names} # returns an array (NOT array ref)
```

But when I store it in some other variable I get this unusual behaviour.

```
say ($conf->{group}->{names}); # some array ref
say ($conf->{group}->{names}[1]); # some string
my @list = $conf->{group}->{names};
say ($list[0]); # same array ref
```

What may be the reason for this behaviour? I want to loop over this array but using `foreach` but unable to do so because of this.

I wish to iterate over the elements of the array, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Please provide a complete example.

Comment: @ikegami modifed the question, there was a typo

Comment: @ikegami its a `hash array reference` not hash

Comment: reference to a hash is what  I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227371/discussion-between-shan-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You claim `$conf->{group}->{names}` is an array as opposed to a reference to one, but that's impossible. Hashes values are scalars; they can't be arrays. This is why we store references to arrays in hashes.

That `$conf->{group}->{names}[1]` works (short for `$conf->{group}->{names}->[1]`) indicates `$conf->{group}->{names}` it's an a reference to an array.<sup>[1]</sup>

You assign this reference to the `@list`, and therefore populate `@list` with this reference. This is why `$list[0]` is this reference.

---

You wish to iterate over the elements of the array. If you had a named array, you would use

```perl
for (@array) {
   ...
}
```

But you have a reference to an array. There are two syntaxes that can be used to accomplish that.

1. The circumfix syntax features a block that returns the reference

   ```perl
   for (@{ $ref }) {   # Or just @$ref when the block contains a simple scalar.
      ...
   }
   ```

   In your case,

   ```perl
   my $ref = $conf->{group}{names}[1];
   for (@$ref) {
      ...
   }
   ```

   or

   ```perl
   for (@{ $conf->{group}{names}[1] }) {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. The postfix (aka "arrow") syntax features can be tacked onto an expression.

   ```perl
   for ($ref->@*) {
      ...
   }
   ```

   In your case,

   ```perl
   my $ref = $conf->{group}{names}[1];
   for ($ref->@*) {
      ...
   }
   ```

   or

   ```perl
   for ($conf->{group}{names}[1]->@*) {
      ...
   }
   ```

   `->@*` requires Perl 5.24+. It's available in Perl 5.20+ by adding both `use feature qw( postderef );` and `no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );`, or by adding `use experimental qw( postderef );`. This is safe because the then-experimental feature was accepted into Perl without change.

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924) and the documentation linked by it.

---

1. I'm assuming you're using `use strict;` as you always should.

Comment: thanks.. I just had to dereference my variables

Comment: Yes, to access a referenced variable, one deferences the reference (by definition).