# mutiple {} in perl script

Tags: perl, syntax

I have this syntax in a perl script and I don't know what it means:
`$string.= "$$info{$id}{free}\t";`.

I am very new to pearl (first time reading a perl script) and I didn't find any useful information for this.

Comment: those are hash references, see: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$info` is a hash reference. This refers to a multi level data structure, with the first level key set by another variable `$id`. Your structure might look something like this:

```perl
my $info = {
  1 => { 
    free => 2,
    used => 3,
  },
  2 => {
    free => 1,
    used => 0,
  },
};
```

The `$id` in this example would be `1` or `2`.

You can read about this in more detail in [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut).

Your code takes the value from inside the data structure and appends it to a variable `$string` followed by a tab character. It looks like it's building a tab separated file, similar to a CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924), `$$info{ $id }` can also be written as `$info->{ $id }`. (I'm not alone in finding the latter much clearer.)

```perl
$info->{ $id }{ free }
```

is short for

```perl
$info->{ $id }->{ "free" }
```

This is just just following two hash element dereferences chained into a single expression:

```perl
my $anon = $info->{ $id };  $anon->{ "free" }
```

`HASHREF->{ KEY }` is used to get the value of a hash element given a reference to a hash and the key of the element.

This means that `$info` is expected to be a reference to a hash. `$info->{ $id }` gets the value of the element with the value of `$id` for key.

Similarly, `$info->{ $id }`/`$anon` is expected to be a reference to a hash. `$anon->{ "free" }` gets the value of the element with key `free`.

For example,

```perl
my $info = {
   machine01 => { 
      free => 100,
      used => 200,
   },
   machine02 => {
      free =>  50,
      used => 450,
   },
};

my $id = "machine01";

say $info->{ $id }{ free };  # 100
```

See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)