# What is the difference between @{$value} and @$value in perl?

Tags: perl

Example:

```
for my $key ( keys %DNS_CSV_FILES){ 
    for my $file (@$DNS_CSV_FILES{$key}){
        print $file; 
    }
}
```

gives the error:

```
Global symbol "$DNS_CSV_FILES" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $DNS_CSV_FILES"?) at dns.pl line 41.
Execution of dns.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

But this code:

```
for my $key ( keys %DNS_CSV_FILES){
    for my $file (@{$DNS_CSV_FILES{$key}}){
        print $file; 
    }
}
```

gives the desired output:

```
file1.txtfile2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`@$x{ $key }` is short for `@{ $x }{ $key }`, not `@{ $x{ $key } }`.

---

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924). Footnote [1] in particular. The curlies can only be omitted around a simple scalar variable.

There is no difference between `@{ $x }` and `@$x`. But that's not what the two snippets are using.

The first is using `@$x{ $key }`, which is short for `@{ $x }{ $key }`.

There is a difference between `@{ $x }{ $key }` and `@{ $x{ $key } }`.

`@foo{ $key }` is a slice of a named array, so `@{ ... }{ $key }` is a slice of a referenced array. `@{ $DNS_CSV_FILES }{ $key }` is therefore a slice of the array referenced by scalar `$DNS_CSV_FILES`.

`@foo` is a array provided by name, so `@{ ... }` is a referenced array. `@{ $DNS_CSV_FILES{ $key } }` is therefore an array referenced by hash element `$DNS_CSV_FILES{ $key }`.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Perl's dereference syntax puts braces around the reference. However, you can leave off the braces if the reference is simple scalar, like `$value`. For anything else, including a hash key lookup, you keep the braces.

That's the old-style "circumfix" notation. Perl v5.24 stabilized the [postfix dereference syntax](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/).

Answer (score 0):

This

```
@$DNS_CSV_FILES{$key}
```

Will from the left side see an array sigil `@` followed by a scalar `$`. This can only be the dereferencing of an array ref. Otherwise the `@` is a syntax error. Despite you putting the hash notation at the end. It is a race condition, of sorts. So it will assume that what follows is a scalar, and not a hash value.

When you clarify by adding extra brackets, it becomes clear what is intended

```
@{   $DNS_CSV_FILES{$key}   }
```

Whatever is inside `@{   }` must be an array ref, and `$....{key}` must be a hash value.