# Perl: Negative range indexing of array reference

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array reference that I would like to slice the last two elements of the array. I found that using `-2..-1` would work. I was using the following syntax:

```
subroutine($var->[-2..-1]);
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $. in range (or flip)
Argument "" isn't numeric in array element
```

I changed the line to this and that worked:

```
subroutine(@$var[-2..-1]);
```

I don't understand why the second way works though and the first doesn't. I thought using the array operator was the same as dereferencing with `@`. Is the context ambiguous with the arrow operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is the dereference operator. `$aref->[$i]` is to an $aref like  `$arr[$i]` is to `@arr`. To get a slice from an array, you need to change the sigil: `@arr[$i, $j]`. It's similar for dereference, but instead of changing the sigil, you first dereference the reference, then slice it:

```
@{ $aref }[$i, $j]
```

which can be shortened to `@$aref[$i, $j]`.

So the `->` operator can only be used for single values for array and hash references. You need `@{}` for slices.

Comment: Additionally -- that error is popping up because Perl thinks you want a scalar in-between `[` and `]` (and not a list) in your subscript, so it assumes `..` is the flip-flop operator instead of the range operator.  See [Range Operators](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Range-Operators) para.3, "In scalar context..."

Comment: Or `$aref->@[$i, $j]`. See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)