# Perl Module File::Modified Files parameter

Tags: perl

The documentation of `File::Modified` says:

```
my $d = File::Modified->new(files=>['Import.cfg','Export.cfg']);
```

The `files` parameter looks to me as being an array.

Why can I not directly hand over an array?

```
my $d = File::Modified->new(files=>@array);
```

This creates a runtime error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing array to subroutine Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380485/passing-array-to-subroutine-perl)

Comment: `files=>@array` would results in `files=>'Import.cfg', 'Export.cfg'=>undef`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `files` parameter is not an array; it is a *reference* to an array.
The [File::Modified POD](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Modified#DESCRIPTION) says:

> `Files`, which takes an array reference to the filenames to watch.

This is why you can not simply pass an array variable like that.

The [square brackets](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Square-Brackets) create a reference to an array, which is different from an array.

As the `perlref` document shows, one way to take a reference to an array is to use the backslash:

```
my $d = File::Modified->new(files => \@array);
```