# Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden

Tags: perl

I am trying to debug a Perl script that is giving me the error

Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden

This seems to be an issue my system having a newer version of perl, but was hoping some can sugegst a quick fix.

The line in question is

```
foreach my $elemName(keys $grammar -> {$groupName})
```

grammer was defined as

```
my $grammar = {};
```

and groupName comes from

```
foreach my $groupName (keys %$grammar)
```

I do not know much about perl, so any help would be appreciated

I have a similar issue with this line

```
push($DbRef->{def_param}{$par_descr}->{dataset}, $blkDs);
```

with error
Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden ...  near "$blkDs)"

I have tried some solutions I have found about dereferencing, but the syntax is very confusing to me.

Comment: `... keys %{ $grammar -> {$groupName} } ...` ?

Answer (score 3):

`keys EXPR` and `push EXPR, LIST` were introduced in 5.14 as an experimental feature.

`keys EXPR` and `push EXPR, LIST` started warning in 5.20 when the concept of warnings for experimental features was introduced.

`keys EXPR` and `push EXPR, LIST` were removed in 5.24 as the experiment was deemed a failure. (The design of `keys EXPR` is fundamentally flawed.)

---

To get the keys of hash, you can use `keys %NAME`. You can also use a hash deference, such as `keys %BLOCK` or `keys EXRP->%*`.

To get the indexes of an array, you can use `keys @NAME`. You can also use an array deference, such as `keys @BLOCK` or `keys EXRP->@*`.

To push scalars onto an array, you can use `push @NAME, LIST`.
You can also use an array deference, such as `push %BLOCK, LIST` or `push EXRP->@*, LIST`.

---

In your case, you want

```perl
keys %{ $grammar -> {$groupName} }
```

or

```perl
keys $grammar -> {$groupName} -> %*   # 5.24+
```

and

```perl
push(@{ $DbRef->{def_param}{$par_descr}->{dataset} }, $blkDs);
```

or

```perl
push($DbRef->{def_param}{$par_descr}->{dataset}->@*, $blkDs);   # 5.24+
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)

Comment: some arrows extra in last 2

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın, They were there in the OP and they're not wrong. `$r->{x}{y}` is short for `$r->{x}->{y}`. It's weird that some of the arrows were included and other weren't, but I wanted to make the minimal change so the OP could see the fix.