# How can I refer to blessed block of code using reference to the object?

Tags: perl, oop

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $obj = bless do { \( my $scalar = 123; ) }, 'Some::Class';
```

How can I get the `$scalar` value using `$obj`?

I had tried it in many ways, but no success.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a blessed block of code. It's a blessed reference to a scalar.

You can get the value '123' using:

```perl
$$obj
```

Answer (score 3):

@tobyink already gave you the answer with `$$obj`. There is also an alternative  `$obj->$*` with newer Perl versions.

But these are hacks circumventing privacy, you should first look into `Some::Class` if it provides some  `->getter` method.

###### Explanation to this "unusual" syntax:

> `my $obj = bless do { \( my $scalar = 123) }, 'Some::Class';`

Perl can bless all kinds of references, like `{...}` or `[...]`.

One normally sees (IMHO in 99% of the cases) blessed hashes, like

`my $obj = bless { key => val, ... }, 'Some::Class';`

But there is no anonymous constructor syntax for scalar refs, that's especially cumbersome when serializing objects.

Now `do { \( my $dummy = 123 ; ) }` does the trick to return a ref to a mutable scalar and the temporary symbol `$dummy` is in the lexical scope of `do` and can't pollute the namespaces.

The `\(...)` is just a shorter syntax, one could also write `do { my $d = 123; \$d }`

***NB:*** Yes, one could also just use `\123` directly but this would be *immutable* because literals are constant, and rarely of use in objects.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a scalar can be done using the `$BLOCK` syntax or the `EXPR->$*` syntax.

```perl
my $val = ${ $obj };

my $val = $$obj;       # Curlies can be omitted in this case.

my $val = $obj->$*;
```

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).