# What's the meaning of the & in threads::shared::share usage in perl？

Tags: perl

Recently, I'm trying to use threads::shared to share some data between threads, and I was confused by the usage of `$var = &share([]);` in [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads::shared), what's the effect of the `&` before `share`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` tells Perl to ignore the prototype.

---

`share` is documented to accept a scalar, an array or a hash.

```perl
share( $scalar_to_share )
share( @array_to_share )
share( %hash_to_share )
```

But it's impossible to pass arrays and hashes to subs. So what's going on?

`share` has a prototype (`\[$@%]`) which changes how the call is made. Rather than evaluating the argument list as usual, a reference to the provided variable is passed instead.

```perl
share( $scalar_to_share )   # Equivalent to `&share( \$scalar_to_share )`
share( @array_to_share )    # Equivalent to `&share( \@array_to_share )`
share( %hash_to_share )     # Equivalent to `&share( \%hash_to_share )`
```

---

What if you want to provide a reference to an anonymous array? You can't just pass a reference, since that would share the scalar.

```perl
my $ref = [];
share( $ref );                # XXX Would share `$ref` instead of the array.
```

As documented, you can simply bypass the prototype.

```perl
my $ref = [];
&share( $ref );               # ok
```

Conveniently, `share` returns its argument.

```perl
my $ref = &share( [] );       # ok
```

You could also provide the array required by the prototype by dereferencing the reference.

```perl
my $ref = share( @{ [] } );   # ok

my $ref = share( []->@* );    # ok
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what's the name of the syntax in last two lines, the syntax of perl is so flexible :sigh.

Comment: `@BLOCK` and `EXPR->@*` are [array dereferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924).

Comment: Thanks ! The matrix is very helpful for understanding deference syntax.