# Accessing array elements in a decoded JSON hash

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I have the following code:

```perl
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS qw/decode_json/;

my $api_response = '{"user":{"id":14897,"data":["foo", "bar", "baz"]}}';
my $user = decode_json($api_response);
$user = $user->{user};

my @data = $user->{data};

print($user->{id}, "\n");  # output: 14897
print("@data", "\n");      # output: ARRAY(0x14200d9b8)
print($data[0], "\n");     # output: ARRAY(0x14200d9b8) why???
print($data[0][0], "\n");  # output: foo
```

This is working fine for me, but it took me a while to figure out that I have to go 2 levels deep into `$data` which, to my eyes, should represent a simple array of strings. Is this expected behaviour, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate, but I am unsure how I'd search for it. Hoping someone can explain it to me like I'm a simple minded PHP programmer ;-)

Comment: It's an arrayref, not an array. Should be using `my $data = $user->{data};`, `print($data->[0], "\n");`, etc.

Comment: [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3A%3ADumper) is good for visualizing what the data looks like.  Like @Shawn said, it's an array ref -- so you have an array `@data` containing a single entry (the reference).

Comment: Ok that last bit is very helpful @JimDavis combined with the answer below and what I read about the arrow rule in perlreftut it explains why my current code works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalars such as hash elements can't be arrays or hashes. But we can store references to arrays hashes and hashes in them. This is the case here.

```perl
my @data = $user->{data};

say "@data";
say $data[0];
```

should be

```perl
my $data = $user->{data};

say "@$data";
say $data->[0];
```

Alternatives:

| postfix | circumfix | circumfix (curlies omitted) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` my $data = $user->{data}; say join " ", $data->@*; say $data->[0]; ``` | ``` my $data = $user->{data}; say "@{ $data }"; say ${ $data }[0]; ``` | ``` my $data = $user->{data}; say "@$data"; say $$data[0]; ``` |

See [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)

Comment: @user20284150, That's bad advice. Don't make a copy of the array and each scalar within it without reason.